# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2' even after installing opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to workon oopencv but the vscode terminal keeps on throwing the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'` even though I have installed opencv by writing `pip install opencv-python` on cmd.

I have also added `"C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\"` to my path .

However, when I create a virtual environment and install opencv on the virtual environment and then workon that environment, my code starts to work and there are no more errors. Why is this happening?

Comment: use ```pip3 install opencv-python```

Comment: because u installed opencv in virtual environment but not in the other one

Comment: i installed opencv in the default environment, and it did not work. After doing workon venv and then again installing opencv in the venv, it works.